# 1D cubic interpolation unequal arrays using Numpy and Scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I need to perform a cubic 1D interpolation over a number of large arrays. I would normally use pandas but I am struggling to use pandas for repeating x-values. From what I understand this can be achieved using numpy. However, I am struggling to setup the arrays correctly. For each x-value there are 50,000 y-values. I cannot repeating this as an example. The example below is for less values but I am hoping to extend it to greater values.

The first entry for the interpolation is (x1, (y1,y0)) and the last entry is (x4,(y4,y10)). Firstly, I do not think I have set the arrays up correctly and secondly, I do not think I am using the interpolation function correctly.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

# setting up x-arrays
x1 = [10] * 10
x2 = [20] * 10
x3 = [30] * 10
x4 = [40] * 10

x_array_tuple = (x1,x2,x3,x4)
x_arrays = np. vstack(x_array_tuple)

# import y-arrays

y1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y4 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

y_array_tuple = (y1,y2,y3,y4)
y_arrays = np. vstack(y_array_tuple)

# interpolation
i_func = interpolate.interp1d(x_arrays,y_arrays, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolation') # the first entry is (x1, (y1,y0)); the last entry is (x4,(y4,y10))
```

This is the error message I get:

raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along "

ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.

How do I perform this interpolation?

Comment: I see two problems here. First, [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) allows to pass `x` as a 1-D array. Second, it expects `x` not to have duplicates.

Comment: I am thinking that I need to perform interp1d(x-arrays (1D),y-arrays(2D)). Is this possible?

Comment: `interp1d` of 1-D x-array and 2-D y-array is possible but `x` must not have duplicates.

Comment: Is the an interpolation function that accept duplicates in order to perform a cubic fit?

Comment: Not that I know of.